# Import Error: No Module named 'xxxx' Specific

Tags: python

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a program in python which takes a URL, copys the source, and pulls all comments out and presents them to the user.

```
import urllib2
import html2text
import PullsCommentsOut.pullscommentsout


url = raw_input('Please input URL with the text you want to analyze: ')
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_content = page.read().decode('utf8')
rendered_content = html2text.html2text(html_content).encode('ascii', 
'ignore')

f = open('file_text.txt', 'wb')
f.write(rendered_content)
f.close()

result = PullsCommentsOut.pullscommentsout(html_content)
print result
```

And my second file, 'PullsCommentsOut'

```
import re


def pullscommentsout():
    def comment_remover(text):
        def replacer(match):
        s = match.group(0)
        if s.startswith('/'):
            print s
            return " "  # note: a space and not an empty string
        else:
            return s

    pattern = re.compile(
        r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"',
        re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
    )
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)

fd = open("test.c", "r")
buf = fd.read()

comment_remover(buf)
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why Python doesn't think I'm not importing the proper module? It doesn't make sense.

I need to add more text so it allows me to post, so, how are you all doing? I'm doing pretty good I guess. No complaints.

Comment: Are they in the same directory? Also, note that all the code outside the function in your second file will get run the moment you import it. I recommend you put that code under a `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition.

Comment: Modules _files_ have to have a `.py` extension, I believe.

Comment: @Shiva they are in the same directory, or rather, the same folder if that's what you mean. I'll look into the if_name thing, though.

Comment: @martineau Put the .py file extension after the entire import statement?

Comment: No, just the file name. i.e. To `import foobar`, there needs to be a file named `foobar.py`.